# Inserting an element at the tail of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am new to data structures. I finally got the hang of adding new element at the beginning of linked list
but now there is another problem. I have watched so many YouTube videos yet the problem isn't solved. I am trying to add an element at the end of this linked list but when I do the first two elements disappear. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(){
        data = 0;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
Node* add_end(Node* a, int new_data){
    Node* ptr, *temp; 
    ptr = a;
    temp = new Node();
    
    temp->data = new_data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    
    while(ptr->next != NULL) {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    
    ptr->next = temp;
    
    return ptr;
}

void print(Node* a){
    while(a != NULL){
        cout << a->data << "  ";
        a = a->next;
    }
}



int main(){
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *second = NULL;
    Node *third = NULL;
    
    head = new Node();
    second = new Node();
    third = new Node();
    
    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;
    
    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;
     
    third->data = 3;
    third->next = NULL;
    
    cout << "Before Adding:\n";
    
    print(head);
    
    head = add_end(head, 4);
            
    cout << "\nAfter Adding: \n";
    
    print(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `add_end` should return the pointer to the head node.

Your current implementation returns the pointer to the second last node, which is calculated in the process of adding element.

You should return `a` instead of `ptr` from the function `add_end`.

Also you should return `temp` before the loop when `ptr` is `NULL`, or `NULL` will be dereferenced and it may lead to runtime error.

Comment: in fact that function can be void as well.. since nothing is modified on 'a', head remains the same.

Comment: @thomachan "add to an empty list" (`NULL` is passed as `a`) case cannot be supported in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't think i would have gotten that explanation anywhere. Can you elaborate that part where you said that ptr points to the second last element? Why does it?